# performing perturbation by adding noise(order of 10^-2) to each element of X

Tags: python, numpy

### Add a noise(order of 10^-2) to each element of X and get the new data set X'

```
             x           y          z            x*x        2*y       2*z+3*x*x     w       target
        0   -0.581066   0.841837    -1.012978   -0.604025   0.841837    -0.665927   -0.536277   0
        1   -0.894309   -0.207835   -1.012978   -0.883052   -0.207835   -0.917054   -0.522364   0
        2   -1.207552   0.212034    -1.082312   -1.150918   0.212034    -1.166507   0.205738    0
        3   -1.364174   0.002099    -0.943643   -1.280666   0.002099    -1.266540   -0.665720   0
        4   -0.737687   1.051772    -1.012978   -0.744934   1.051772    -0.792746   -0.735054   0
```

---

```
X = data.drop(['target'], axis=1).values
Y = data['target'].values
```

how to add this order of 10^-2 ?

Comment: What's the distribution of this random value?

Comment: Gaussian distribution

Comment: I assume mean would be zero, what's the standard deviation?

Comment: not given anything ,only we have to add order of 10^-2 ,that's only the condition has been given

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly noise in the order of 10^-2 should mean. I use that as the standard deviation for the gaussian distribution of your noise.

```
import numpy as np
# your code
mean, sigma = 0, 0.01
X_with_noise = X + np.random.normal(mean, sigma, size=X.shape)
```